# If I press a third arrow key while holding two others, why does it not run the keyPressed() method?

Tags: java, keylistener

When I press and hold an arrow key it is sent repeatedly to the keyPressed() method that is part of KeyListener. If I press and hold another arrow key, that arrow key is then repeatedly sent to the keyPressed() method. If I however press and hold a third arrow key, that key is not sent to the keyPressed() method at all. The other held down keys also stop being sent to the keyPressed() method. If I press a different key on the keyboard while holding two arrow keys, it is correctly sent to the keyPressed() method, although not repeatedly, which it is if held down while no other keys are held down.

Short version: If I hold two arrow keys and press a third, it does not get sent to the keyPressed() method that is part of KeyListener.

Why is this?

Comment: Could be an issue with your keyboard. Does it have N-Key-Rollover? Else it's not guaranteed how many keys can be pressed at the same time. It also depends on where the keys are on the keyboard. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the keyboard itself, it sometimes can not handle multiple keys pressed at the same time.